# Выравнивание блоков по ширине в CSS

Tags: css3, html, css

Итак, дано: div.parent с известными шириной и высотой; div.sub (Их N штук, они лежат внутри div.parent и имеют одну т ту же ширину и высоту W); Отступы между блоками справа равны M и заданы для всех блоков, кроме последнего div.sub. Возможно ли такое реализовать средствами CSS? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.parent .sub:not(:last-child){
   border: 5px solid red;
 }
```

как то так, там сам колдуй с отступами